# Use the ref principle on the new not null test

Tags: c#, notnull, c#-8.0

I do not know what it is called exactly, but for now I will refer to it as 'not null test'. In C# 8 there is a new behavior which allows to test if an object is not null e.g.:

```cs
Foo foo = new Foo();

if(foo is { })
{
    //foo is not null
}
```

You can also extract properties from this object:

```cs
public class Foo
{
    public int Bar { get; set; }
}

Foo foo = new Foo();

if(foo is { Bar: var bar })
{
    //Foo is not null and bar contains the value of the property of the foo instance
}
```

So far so good, but I imagine it to be similar to something like this:

```cs
public bool GetBar(Foo foo, out int bar)
{
    if(foo is null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    bar = foo.Bar;
    return true;
}
```

Which would be used as something like this:

```cs
Foo foo = new Foo();

if(GetBar(foo, out var bar))
{
    //Foo is not null and bar contains the value of the property of the foo instance
}
```

Now my actual question: Is there any way I could use the behavior of ref? Which would look something like this:

```cs
if(foo is { Bar: ref var bar })
{
    //Foo is not null and bar contains the value of the property of the foo instance
}
```

I would understand if this does not exist since `out ref` does not exist either. So is there any way you can do this, or is there anything that would speak against it?

Comment: as far as I understand it, the notation of _{ }_ means 'some object'. Objects do not have a concept of reference variables. The _ref_ keyword is used for function parameters. So the answer would be no

Comment: Well I just use _ref_ just an example, in order to clarify what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern you are using is the **property pattern** from the C#8 [pattern matching feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#more-patterns-in-more-places).

> The property pattern enables you to match on properties of the object examined.

If I'm getting your question correctly, you'd like not only to get the property value but also a possibility to change that value in the object being matched.

```
if (foo is { Bar: ref var bar })
{
    bar = 42; // now foo.Bar is 42 too
}
```

In order that `ref` semantic to work, it has to be supported by the language and by the compiler.

However, C# doesn't allow you to use `ref` with a property - and that's true for any C# version. The reason is obvious: your get-set property `Bar` (as any other C# property) will be compiled to two methods: `get_Bar` and `set_Bar`. So in fact you have a method, not a value - thus, you can't `ref` a value a method returns (okay, there are `ref return`s, but those don't apply to property getters).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I guess it could work with Fields at least then, but I get the problem in general.